# How do I create an If statement to classify a number between a range that is on another table?

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to create a column in the "Data" section in powerbi, not power query. I have a 1 table that contains ID numbers and another table that contains the type of ID number with its given range that it needs to fall under. Each column is type "Text". The example below contains two columns

Below is the code I am working on

```
Answer = LOOKUPVALUE('Table 2'[Type],'Table 2'[Range],
                      IF(Contains('Table 2','Table 2'[Range],"-") = TRUE,
                      IF(AND('Table 1'[ID] >= Left('Table 2'[Range],"-"),
                     'Table 1'[ID] < Right('Table 2'[Range],"-")),
                     'Table 1'[ID],0),'Table 1'[ID]))
```

Below is an example I am trying to replicate:

[image]  [image]

What would be the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm kind of confused by this, are you given `Table 2` with columns `[Range]` and `[Type]` - and then you are given `Table 1` with just column `[ID]`? Then you are trying to fill in the `[Answer]` column?

Comment: Table 2 is given and table 1 has a list of IDs. I am trying to create a column called "Answer"

IF ID  says 4 it is in the range of "1-10" so the answer will be "I" from the "Type" column. If ID says "42" it falls under the range "41-50" from the "Type" column. If there is a value in the "Range" column that does not have a "-" then if ID equals that specific number it will contain that type. That is why there is a "Special" value in the "Type" column

Comment: Table 2 needs a column with a numeric value for the lookup, not a text string like you have right now. Let's assume the column is called RangeStart and has only the lower numbers of the pair, i.e. 1, 11, 21, etc. Then you can do an approximate match. Google it.